# Role of gl.vertexAttrib

Tags: shader, webgl, vertex-buffer-object

I'm re-learning WebGL, and I stumbled upon [gl.vertexAttribPointer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/vertexAttribPointer) and [gl.vertexAttrib](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/vertexAttrib). To my knowledge, gl.vertexAttribPointer tells the GPU how the data in the currently binded buffer relates to the vertex attributes. But, I'm confused on what gl.vertexAttrib does. It seems like it also sends data to the GPU, but without the use of a buffer. Can anybody explain it's role to me?

Comment: See [What is glVertexAttrib (vs. glVertexAttribPointer) used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718976/what-is-glvertexattrib-versus-glvertexattribpointer-used-for#7719060). Essentially, they're the same thing, but `glVertexAttrib` is for the older immediate mode.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think I understand the difference now. One sets a constant value, and the other links the values to a buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gl.vertexAttribPointer is used when different vertices should have different values, and gl.vertexAttrib is used when all vertices should have the same values, and you don't want to use a special shader with a uniform.